# Replacing a thermal cut-off with a potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer, heat

I think this is a pretty basic question but I don't know much about electronics and I could really use some help.  I'm trying to modify a hot air popcorn popper to use as a coffee roaster.  The popper has a thermal cut-off switch that will cut power to the heating element when it reaches somewhere around 350 degrees.  That temperature is too low for roasting coffee so I've removed that switch.  This works but I'd like to get a little more control over the heating element.  I know that I can put a simple toggle switch in place of the thermal cut-off and just switch the heater on and off but I'm wondering if it's possible to put a potentiometer in its place so that I can vary the the heating element.  My concern is that this may destroy the pot or worse.  The thermal switch is rated for 125V and 15A and the heating element runs at over 1000W.  If anyone has any ideas about what I can do, I'd love to hear them.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very ill judged plan, because the whole thing will have been designed to operate safely at a given temperature, and simply removing that limit represents a huge risk.  It _is_ possible to make such an informed assessment of whether higher temperature use is possible, but if you need to ask for the advice, I would strongly suggest you don't have the required skills...

Answer (score 5):

Not wise.

This thing is designed to operate at the 350 ° and the design was tested to be safe under those conditions. It's definitely *not* made for higher temperatures, and when you operate it at these higher temperatures anything can happen. The thermal switch isn't just functional, it's a safety component. Don't do it.

A potentiometer won't be enough, either. You would have to measure temperature (which is now done by the switch, which just recognizes one particular temperature), and compare the voltage the sensor gives with the voltage you set with the potmeter. And then you use the result of that comparison to switch the heater on or off.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  I understand your concerns about safety.  I was surprised how many people are doing this and talking about it online.  It does seem like a fire hazard.  There is a thermal fuse in the device (as well as the switch) in case things really get out of hand but when you modify it like this it gets a lot hotter than it was designed for.

Comment: @Dave - The thermal fuse should give you clue about the risks. If just the switch would do, then why would they need the fuse? When overheating this popper can be a real danger of burning down your house, that's why the fuse is used as extra safety measure, in case the switch should fail. The fuse costs money, and they wouldn't add it if it weren't useful.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use a potentiometer in place of the thermal switch.

The reason is the power and inefficiencies involved - even if you could find a pot rated to handle up to ~470W (most unlikely) it would be terribly inefficient as the pot would have to dissipate this in heat, so it would turn into another heating element.

The way to do it would be to sense the temperature and switch the element on/off accordingly. This can be done in various ways:

Mechanically - using a bimetallic strip switch (like the ones typically found in old central heating thermostats)
Using a simple temperature sensor (e.g. thermocouple/thermistor) and a comparator which turns a triac in series with the heating element on/off (as Steven mentions)
Using the same type of setup as above but replace the comparator with a PID controller and adjustable duty cycle for a more accurate regulation.

I would agree with Steven though, and say none of this is advisable given the fact it was not designed to operate at these temperatures. If you want to go ahead then it would be better to buy a new element rated for these temperatures, and do similar for the enclosure (whatever that would be, maybe some kind oven roasting pan/pot, or a coffee roasting tin?)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about better ways to do this.  I suppose the simplest option would be to just use a thermometer to watch the temp then add a switch for the heating element and control it manually.

I agree with you and Steve though that the bigger issue is the fire hazard.  The thing is clearly not designed to operate at 450+ degrees which is where you need to get to roast coffee.  I know there are lots of people doing this regardless of the risk, or maybe they don't recognize the risk.  I wouldn't be surprised if there have already been some accidents.

Thanks again for your help